# Input format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, input

How can I force the format for this example in an Excel cell?

3.3H73 (number, period, number, letter, number number)

Comment: Use a custom formula in Data Validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a slightly long custom data validation formula. On the ribbon, select **DATA** then **Data Validation**.

If the cell you want to validate is A1 then copy and paste this formula in here (in place of `=ISERROR(...)`):

[image: enter custom data validation formula here]

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),MID(A1,2,1)=".",ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,3,1))),ISTEXT(MID(A1,4,1)),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))),LEN(A1)=6),1,0)
```

Breaking this down, we're simply checking that every character in turn is either a number, text, or the `.` character by position, and that the overall length of the string entered is correct.

```
=IF(
  AND(                                 --- ALL conditions below must be TRUE
    ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)))        --- char #1 must be a number
   ,MID(A1,2,1)="."                    --- char #2 must be .
   ,ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,3,1)))       --- char #3 must be a number
   ,ISTEXT(MID(A1,4,1))                --- char #4 must be text
   ,ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))       --- char #5&6 must be numbers
   ,LEN(A1)=6                          --- the string must be 6 characters long
  )
 ,1,0)                                 --- if true output 1, else 0
```